# old function don't work in php 5.35

Tags: php

```
function goto($herf) {
    echo ("<script>window.location.href='".$herf."'</script>");
}
```

the above function work well before php 5.3.5, after i upgrade my php to 5.3.5, the following error displayed.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_GOTO, expecting T_STRING or '(' in C:\xampp\htdocs\directory\directory\directory\directory\file.php on line 9

what is that error refer?

Comment: You don't you use `header("Location; http://");` instead?
Also, what is the $href, when you call this function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They added [goto to the php language](http://us.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.goto.php), which makes it a reserved word and no longer available as a function name.

> The goto operator is available as of PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 2):

So solution is:

```
function location($herf) {
    echo ("<script>window.location.href='".$herf."'</script>");
}
```